# Is it "legal" to switch $\forall x$ with $\forall s\forall t$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the book *The Foundations of Mathematics* by Kenneth Kunen, in a chapter about set theory formalizations, the following first order logic sentence is provided (referred to as the *Axiom of Comprehension/Separation Schema*):

$\forall z \Big (\exists y \color{red}{\forall x} \big ( \color{red}{x} \in y \leftrightarrow x \in z \land \varphi(\color{red}{x}) \big ) \Big )$. I have colored in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ the variable that I will be focusing on for the remainder of this question.

Consider the following two sets:

$A = \{ x \in \mathbb N \ |\  x \lt 5\}$.

$B = \{ \langle s, t \rangle \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \ |\ s \lt 5 \land t\lt 4 \}$

---

Now, let's say I wanted to look at set $A$ and confirm that it exists through the perspective of the Axiom of Comprehension Schema:

$\exists y \forall x (x \in y \ \leftrightarrow \ x \in \mathbb N \land x \lt 5)$ where $\varphi(x):= x \lt 5$. Cool. Set A exists.

To confirm set $B$'s existence, however, I run into an issue when it comes to inserting the predicate $\varphi$:

$\exists y \forall x (x \in y \ \leftrightarrow \ x \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \ \land \text{something} )$

I use the phrase "$\text {something}$" because "$\varphi (x)$" does **not** appear to *decompose* correctly into a statement about two variables...i.e. $\varphi(x)$ cannot be used to represent "$s \lt 5 \land t \lt 4$" because $s$ and $t$ are not necessarily equal, and therefore do not represent one object $x$.

---

A quick fix seems to be to switch $\forall x$ with $\forall s \forall t$ in order to generate the following statement:

$\exists y \forall s \forall t (\langle s,t \rangle \in y \ \leftrightarrow \ \langle s,t \rangle \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \ \land s \lt 5 \land t \lt 4  )$

**I am uncertain why this is something that is allowed**. Specifically, this seems to suggest that $\forall x  \ \varphi(x)$ is 'semantically' (regular English definition) equivalent to $\forall s \forall t \ \varphi (s,t)$.

From what I understand about first order logic, $\forall x \ \varphi (x)$ essentially means "For all **singular** objects in the domain of discourse, the following sentence about a **singular** object is true". Comparatively, I interpret $\forall s \forall t \ \varphi(s,t)$ as saying "For any **two** objects in the domain of discourse, the following sentence is true about **two** objects".

Is the syntax "$\ s,t\ $" a singular object in the domain of discourse? It doesn't strike me as one...hence my confusion.

Any input is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I think I have found a workaround to show that $B$ is a set, but I am unsure about your core claim of replacing $\forall x$ with $\forall s\forall t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the **projection functions** - or rather, the projection *relations*. These are the binary relations $\pi_0(x,y)$ and $\pi_1(x,y)$, which we read as "$x$ is an ordered pair with left coordinate $y$" and "$x$ is an ordered pair with right coordinate $y$." Note that the expression "$u=\langle v,w\rangle$" is really shorthand for "$\pi_0(u,v)\wedge\pi_1(u,w)$."

Writing out the projection relations in terms of $\in$ alone is a good exercise. Once you've done this, you can produce $B$ by applying Separation to the formula

$$\varphi(x)\equiv \forall s,t(\pi_0(x,s)\wedge \pi_1(x,t)\rightarrow s<5\wedge t<4).$$

Separation applied to this formula, with "container set" $z=\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, says that there is a set $B$ consisting of exactly those $a$ which are elements of $z$ and which satisfy $\varphi$ - and this $B$ is precisely what we want.

Comment: If you recall this post I made a while back (which you responded to) --> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855153/method-explanation-for-proof-used-in-the-following-proposition-if-sz-z-tz-z, there was an issue of interpreting the universal quantifier of a single object as the universal quantifier of two objects. In particular, in one of your comments under you answer, you wrote, "But the universal quantifier over $v$ really is over $x$ and $y$ as well - they're introduced as components of $v$". Is this a similar concept? Or unrelated?

Comment: @S.Cramer Yup, if memory serves (it's been a while) this is exactly what's implicitly going on there: we can quantify over (say) pairs by quantifying over individual elements and then using projections.

Comment: B-e-a-utiful. Thank you! Let me digest this answer for a little bit now. Cheers~

Comment: For clarity, your sentence "...$\pi_0(x,y)$ and $\pi_1(x,y)$, which we read as '$x$ is an ordered pair with left coordinate $y$' and '$x$ is an ordered pair with right coordinate $y$' " is specific to MY question, yes? More generally, we would say, for example, $\pi_0(x,y)$ is read as, "$x$ is an element of a cartesian product and $y$ is the $0$th index (or 'most far left component') of that element". Is that correct?

Comment: @S.Cramer Sure - although it's not really established notation (it's usually clear from context though). Really, once you're looking beyond pairs you should be thinking about tuples as *functions* from an indexing set (recall that these are themselves sets of ordered pairs). At that point, we're just talking about **function evaluation**. This is necessary to say e.g. "every coordinate of this tuple is nonzero" or similar - if we introduce a separate formula for each coordinate, things get messy *(or impossible!)*. See also the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828931/28111).

Comment: I thought about your comment ("Writing out the projection relations in terms of $\in$ alone is a good exercise") and came up with something that I hoped you might direct me on. I interpreted that recommendation of yours as saying, "Use set theory FOL to describe what exactly $\pi_{n \in \mathbb N} (x,y)$ means". There are 3 important things to note: 1) $x$ needs to be a function (i.e. $x=\{\langle 0,a \rangle , \langle 0,b \rangle ... \}$ would not qualify, 2) $x$'s domain needs to be the subset of $\mathbb N$, and 3) encode the necessary property of $y$ as it relates to the subscript $n$

Comment: Using $\pi_0$ as our example: $\langle x,y \rangle \in \pi_0 \iff \text{dom}(x) \subseteq \mathbb N \land \forall z \big (z \in \text{dom}(x) \rightarrow \exists ! y \varphi(x,y) \big) \land \exists w \big (w \in x \land \forall z (z\in w \rightarrow 0 \in z) \land (\bigcup w \setminus 0 = \emptyset \rightarrow y=0) \land (\bigcup w \setminus 0 \neq \emptyset \rightarrow y \in \bigcup w \setminus 0) \big )$

Comment: For the above expression, I used the Kuratwoski implementation of an ordered pair, which is why some of those statements are written the way that they are

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible workaround in order to show that $B$ is a set:

You could use a single variable $w$ (to encode the pair $\langle s,t\rangle$) and then use
$$\phi(w):=\exists s\exists t\;\, w=\,\langle s,t\rangle \land s<5 \land t<4$$

Comment: Note to the OP that this is the same as my answer, but snappier: "$w=\langle s,t\rangle$" is shorthand for "$\pi_0(w,s)\wedge\pi_1(w,t)$" for appropriate projection formulas $\pi_0,\pi_1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose $\varphi(x)$ to be $x_0<5\land x_1<4$, if you have the notation $x=\langle x_0,\,x_1\rangle$ for $2$-tuples. Mathematicians often abbreviate this by saying $\varphi(\langle s,\,t\rangle)$ iff $s<5\land t<4$, with it being taken as implicit that $\neg\varphi(x)$ whenever $x$ isn't a $2$-tuple (although that wouldn't matter in the present context).

However, the existence of a Cartesian product $X\times Y$, such as $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, is proven with several axioms:

- First we convince ourselves ordered pairs exist, e.g. on Kuratowski's definition with unordered-pair (an axiom in Zermelo set theory, a theorem in ZF) repeatedly.
- Replacement tells us first that $X\times\{a\}$ exists for each $a\in Y$, then that there is a set of these Cartesian products.
- We can now take a union to get $X\times Y$.

If this question presupposes we already accept the above, we can prove $B$ exists by writing $B=X\times Y$ with$$X=\{s\in\Bbb N|s<5\},\,Y=\{t\in\Bbb N|t<4\},$$which lets us use comprehension twice, with very obvious choices of $\varphi$.