# In set theory what is A* and how does it differ from the power set of A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having a difficult time understanding the use of $A^*$ and how it differs from the usage of a power set.

$A^*$ is defined as *"the set of all (finite) lists over A"*. I understand $\wp(A)$ to be the power set of A defined as *"the set of all subsets of A."*

How is *"all lists over A"* different from *"all subsets of A"*?

Here are both definitions as denoted in my textbook:

$$A^* := \{[a_1,...,a_n]\ |\ n \in \mathbb N;\ a_1,...,a_n \in A\}$$

$$\wp(A) = \{X\ |\ X \subseteq A\}$$

Comment: Might have something to do with finiteness...

Comment: @KentaS power sets already have a unique definition for finite subsets. And to clarify, in the definition I am working with regarding lists over A, the word "finite" is in parentheses. Edit: Edited the question to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: Lists are probably ordered, and maybe can have duplicates too. This should be clear from the context.

Comment: Yes, in the usual definition of $A^*$ as used in Computer Science, these are ordered and can have duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several differences:

- Finite lists are **ordered** (and allow **duplicates**) while sets are not: e.g. $$[1,2,1]\quad\mbox{and}\quad[2,1,1]$$ are different lists, while $$\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}=\{1,2,1\}.$$
- Finite lists are **finite** while elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ (= subsets of $A$) need not be: if we take $A=\mathbb{N}$, then the set of even numbers is an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ but there is no finite sequence which in any sense "corresponds" to it. Meanwhile, subsets of $A$ are at most as big as $A$, while finite lists can have arbitrarily large finite lengths - this means that if $A$ is finite there will be finite lists of elements of $A$ which are "longer than $A$ is big" (consider e.g. $A=\{1,2\}$ and the finite list $[1,2,1,2,1,2]$).

So $A^*$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ are really very different objects.

---

On a technical note, it's a good idea at this point to give a formal definition of "finite sequence." The definition you've given isn't really rigorous, since the notation "$[...]$" is itself undefined.

The most convenient one winds up being: "a finite list (of elements of some set $X$) is a function $f$ with domain $\{i\in\mathbb{N}:i<n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (and codomain $X$)." We think of $f(i)$ as the $i$th term of $f$.

This winds up being a very useful definition in that it generalizes broadly - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828931/28111).

Comment: Thank you for the help, Noah. I had a weak moment of confusion seeing elementary set theory after years of studying. I also found your further definition of a "finite sequence" quite useful.

Answer (score 5):

The two have basically nothing in common. $A^*$ is the set of all (finite) words you can write using the elements of $A$ as letters, whereas $P(A) $ is the set of all subsets of $A$.

As a very simple example, if $A = \{a\} $, then $A^* = \{\varepsilon, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, \dots\} $ ($\varepsilon $ is the empty word) whereas $P(A) =\{\emptyset, \{a\} \} $.